# Update checkbox in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox, laravel-5

I have check box like this:

```
<input {{isset($shop['private_post'])&&$shop['private_post']=='Yes' ? 'checked' : ''}} id="private_post" value="Yes" type="checkbox" name="private_post">
```

in controller :

```
$shop= shop::find($request['id']);
$shop->update($request->all());
```

In edit mode When  I checkbox true work correctly but when I unchecked checkbox dose not work.
I create dynamically checkbox and I can not use this command

```
If(!isset($request['private_post']))
$request['private_post']=0;
$shop= shop::find($request['id']);
$shop->update($request->all());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" value="0" name="private_post">    
<input {{isset($shop['private_post'])&&$shop['private_post']=='Yes' ? 'checked' : ''}} id="private_post" value="Yes" type="checkbox" name="private_post">
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

**In Blade**

```
{!! Form::checkbox('private_post', '1', Input::old('private_post', 1)) !!}
```

**In Controller**

```
$request['private_post'] = isset($request['private_post']) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I can not use `$data['private_post'] = isset($data['private_post']) ? 1 : 0;` in controller

Comment: I know but my problem is I don`t know which fields is checkbox.

Comment: as per your question you mention that 'private_post' is your checkbox.

Comment: Yes but in end of post I said that I can not use this commands

Comment: No because a lot of files and classes

Comment: then now only god can help you. Because he know everything without show any thing. :(