# Read file from specific line until another specific line in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, readfile

I have file like this

```
#####
....
....
.....
###one
... 
...
...
###two
.... 
....
#####
```

I want read from `###one` until `###two`
I don't want to read line by line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested, this works perfectly:

```
preg_match('/###one(.*?)###two/s', $fileContents, $output);

echo $output[1];
```

Comment: This is the right answer, but to OP, please note that this requires reading in the entire file. Reading it line by line may be a lot better, depending on the size of the file and how your application is built.

Comment: Thanks I test it tomorrow,my file size is small and can you see this post

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290629/update-checkbox-in-laravel-controller/37290702?noredirect=1#comment62106046_37290702

Answer (score 2):

Alternative way for consideration but also need to read the entire file:

```
<?php
$s = file_get_contents('the_file'); 
$ans = explode('###two', explode('###one', $s, 2)[1], 2)[0]; 
echo $ans;
```